# place node_modules folder in separate folder

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install, create-react-app

we are using create-react-app for building react application. All the dependencies will be installed in current project folder under node_modules. But the requirement is shouldn't to be install it in current project folder. It should be in some other location and our application should point that location for libraries. so please help me to implement this functionality.

Thanks,
Narsi p

Answer (score 0):

**Global Setting**

Set the prefix location of node_modules

```
npm config set prefix "$(pwd)/custom/location/node/modules"
```

Here `${pwd}` is the current working directory

**Project Level Setting**

```
npm install --prefix /custom/node_modules/location
```

OR

```
NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=/custom/node_modules/location npm install
```

Comment: It effects all the projects, which are running under the same node. But requirement is only the current project should have separate external node_modules folder.

Comment: @narsi Answer has been updated. Check under the `Project Level Setting`

Comment: how to set NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX in windows? I tried as environment variable. But not working